# Getting rid of excessive elements while copying data from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to parse file manager.xml to get a proper structure of data I need. Example of manager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="koi8-r"?>
<manager>
        <priv id="pr.screen.access" caption="c.screen.access">
                <priv id="pr.screen.category.documents" caption="c.main.documents">
                        <priv id="pr.screen.category.documents.rcn" caption="c.main.documents.rcn">
                                <priv id="pr.screen.category.documents.rcn.create" caption="c.main.documents.rcn.create"/>
                        </priv>
                </priv>
        </priv>
        <priv id="pr.screen.category.archives" caption="c.main.archives"/>
        <priv id="pr.screen.category.documents.rcn.create_as" caption="c.main.documents.rcn.create_as" parent="pr.screen.access"/>
        <priv id="pr.screen.category.transport_management.documents" caption="c.main.transport_management.documents"/>
        <caption id="c.screen.access">
                <loctext lang="ru" long="access"/>
        </caption>
        <caption id="c.main.documents">
                <loctext lang="ru" long="documents"/>
        </caption>
        <caption id="c.main.documents.rcn">
                <loctext lang="ru" long="rcn"/>
        </caption>
        <caption id="c.main.documents.rcn.create">
                <loctext lang="ru" long="rcn_create"/>
        </caption>
        <caption id="c.main.archives">
                <loctext lang="ru" long="archives"/>
        </caption>
        <caption id="c.main.documents.rcn.create_as">
                <loctext lang="ru" long="rcn_create-as"/>
        </caption>
        <caption id="c.main.transport_management.documents">
                <loctext lang="ru" long="transport_documents"/>
        </caption>
</manager>
```

Basically I need to copy all "priv" elements with all nested elements and also find "priv" elements with "parent" attribute and put it into respective "priv" element with "id" attribute equal to "parent".

Besides that I also need to add "caption_ru" attribute for every "priv" element with the value fetched from attribute "long" of "loctext" element which is inside "caption" element where "id" attribute is equal to "caption" attribute of "priv". This part is working, but is there any chance that it's better to be solved by using xsl:key function?

I have next xslt, which is working almost as intended, but I am stuck with extra "priv" elements which I get after tranformation and I can't find any way to get rid of them:
xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="koi8-r"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="koi8-r" version="1.0"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:attribute name='caption_ru'>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//manager/caption[@id=current()/@caption]/loctext[@lang='ru']/@long"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | priv[not(@parent)]"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="nested_priv"/>
                        <!--xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="//manager/priv[@parent=current()/@id]"/>
                        </xsl:copy-->

                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="nested_priv">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <!--xsl:attribute name='caption_ru'>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//manager/caption[@id=current()/@caption]/loctext[@lang='ru']/@long"/>
                        </xsl:attribute-->
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="//manager/priv[@parent=current()/@id]"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I get after transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="koi8-r"?>
<manager caption_ru="">
  <priv caption_ru="access" id="pr.screen.access" caption="c.screen.access">
    <priv caption_ru="documents" id="pr.screen.category.documents" caption="c.main.documents">
      <priv caption_ru="rcn" id="pr.screen.category.documents.rcn" caption="c.main.documents.rcn">
        <priv caption_ru="rcn_create" id="pr.screen.category.documents.rcn.create" caption="c.main.documents.rcn.create">
          <priv/>
        </priv>
        <priv/>
      </priv>
      <priv/>
    </priv>
    <priv>
      <priv caption_ru="rcn_create-as" id="pr.screen.category.documents.rcn.create_as" caption="c.main.documents.rcn.create_as" parent="pr.screen.access">
        <priv/>
      </priv>
    </priv>
  </priv>
  <priv caption_ru="archives" id="pr.screen.category.archives" caption="c.main.archives">
    <priv/>
  </priv>
  <priv caption_ru="transport_documents" id="pr.screen.category.transport_management.documents" caption="c.main.transport_management.documents">
    <priv/>
  </priv>
  <manager/>
</manager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="koi8-r" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="caption" match="caption" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/manager">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="priv"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="priv">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="caption_ru">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('caption', @caption)/loctext/@long" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="priv"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello there. This solves half of my task, since I still need to move "priv" elements which has "parent" attribute to "priv" elements with the equal "id" attribute. At the moment I have added <xsl:copy-of select="//manager/priv[@parent=current()/@id]"/> to "priv" template, but it doesn't add "caption_ru" attribute. I am trying to fix it with another xsl:copy right now.

Comment: I've got the proper result now, the script itself is posted beneath as an answer, I hope it is a correct move from me. Thanks a lot @user3016153!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with xsl listed above which is based on the answer of user3016153 whom I am very thankful. I am not sure should I accept his answer or not, but I did since it was very helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="koi8-r" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="caption" match="caption" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="child_priv" match="priv" use="@parent"/>

<xsl:template match="/manager">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="priv[not(@parent)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="priv">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="caption_ru">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('caption', @caption)/loctext[@lang='ru']/@long" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="priv"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child_priv',current()/@id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Oleg, your two priv templates are identical - you only need one. I would also consider using another key for selecting the privs with matching "parent" attribute.

Comment: @user3016153 thank you again, followed both of your directives and it worked like a charm. Using key dramatically inscreased performance: for a file with a size of 25Mb it went from 2 minutes 15 seconds down to 2 seconds. It was a great luck to get this task and you to help me with it so I could get brief conception of xslt pportunities.

Comment: Looks good. Just curious: do you really need the `[@lang='ru']` predicate to select the loctext? In your example, each caption has only one loctext child.

Comment: @user3016153 yes, since my example is the adapted version of the original file where there are two different captions for each privilege: in english (en) and in russian (ru).